# Adding formatting to table in outlook with Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I am trying to add a table to my Excel VBA-generated e-mail, but when adding the formatting, it does not work.

I am using the following line of code to add the formatting and value to the table

```
tableHTML = tableHTML & "<td style='" & GetCellStyle(cell) & "'>" & cell.Value & "</td>"
```

The GetCellStyle returns the following

```
background-color:00AECE;font-weight:bold;font-style:normal;color:FFFFFF;
```

I simply add the HTMLTable to the body string.

However, the outputted table does not retain any of the formatting other than the font-weight. What I am doing wrong? Can VBA not make a table with color formatting in outlook?

Comment: Add a `#` before the color codes, just in case. Or, use named colors and check the result.